# How we can handle exceptions for an ASP.NET MVC app on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

Below is how I am handling exception in my ASP.NET MVC application.

- Created a Base Controller and overridden OnException method to catch all ASP.NET MVC pipeline errors.
- To capture errors which are beyond ASP.NET MVC pipeline. i.e. 404 - I am using CustomError tag in web.config.

Now, suppose my application is down and not running, then I still want my users to display some error page and want it to configure on IIS level. Could anyone please explain me how we can achieve that and I would also like to know the priority. I mean I want that priority of IIS error should be least.

Comment: looks similar to discussion https://forums.iis.net/t/1180842.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When your app is under maintenance, you need to provide a HttpRedirect to an empty page, which says "Please try after X time, due to upgrade". Your main app should remain there. When any user comes to your main app, it will immediately redirect to the empty app instead of using your app's code.
Here's how to setup redirect on IIS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/